# Resize a picked image from gallery with Picasso

Tags: android, image, android-studio, gallery, picasso

I have a code that picks a image from gallery, set it in a ImageView for use as profile picture, but this code give error when i load the app cause the picture is too big .

So many persons said me to use the Picasso for resize this picked picture but i really dont know how to do it, if someone know how to do it please help me cause i am so long trying to do it and i cant.

this is the code that i pick and store the picture:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("picturePath", picturePath).commit()



        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.User);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
       cursor.close();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First take Your path and call function**

```
  @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

  String   mImageNewPath=compressImage(picturePath);

   // used this mImageNewPath itis compress image path
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("picturePath", picturePath).commit()



    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.User);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
   cursor.close();


 }
```

**function To Reduce size without Loosing quality take this in class just copy to class**

```
    public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

    float maxHeight = 816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
        imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
        actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
        actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
        actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
            scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filename;

    }

    public String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Folderpath");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    return uriSting;

    }
    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
    }
    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
    }
```

**Permission**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Set also this as runtime for android 6.0 Marashmallow**

```
     public boolean checkPermissionForExternalStorage(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


   if(!checkPermissionForExternalStorage())
       {

      if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

     }
```

Comment: what should i put in this mImageNewPath acording with my code?

Comment: your picture path I already take your picture path.......



String   mImageNewPath=compressImage(picturePath);

mImageNewPath is new path of comress image

Comment: i add it to my code but stay as never used. sorry but i am really a beginner in coding, where i must add this line of code?